# python setup.py sdist from Git repository

Tags: python, git, distribute

I want to create tarball with my package automatically for using in installer (another app).
Code is stored in Git repository on Bitbucket.

Now, for creation tarball manually I need:

- clone repo
- checkout to specific branch
- run `python setup.py sdist`

and tarball will be in `dist` directory.

Is there any tool for this purpose?
If no, I'll just implement own tool.

Comment: `git clone repo; cd repo; git checkout specific_branch; python setup.py sdist` - and a tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [zest.releaser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zest.releaser). It has also [customupload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gocept.zestreleaser.customupload) plugin if you need to put the tarball on some server.

[My tutorial for zest.releaser](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/08/14/high-quality-automated-package-releases-for-python-with-zest-releaser/).

Not sure how well it works if your branch and tag naming conventions differ much from what the most Python packages do.